# Waiting icon / message in xpages

Tags: xpages, ssjs

I want to use some waiting dialog / icon / image when code is running. Once code is finished want to stop that icon. I have gone through material available on web but failed to get or understand.

I am using SSJS script which calls agent at back end. It tooks 20-30 seconds in processing.

I have gone through but don't know the utilization?

https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=bootstrap-standby-dialog

http://xpagesera.blogspot.com/2012/05/add-ajax-loading-control-in-xpages-for.html

http://lotusnotus.com/lotusnotus_en.nsf/dx/xpages-tip-a-modal-waiting-dialog-for-background-processes..htm

I have tried the following It's working fine with browsers for IBM Notes 9.0.1 but not working in XPiNC. Where I am using One UI V 2.1 its not working in XPiNC or in Web Client.

```
   <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:dojoModule name="extlib.dijit.ExtLib"></xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:dojoModule name="extlib.dijit.Loading"></xp:dojoModule>
   </xp:this.resources>
```

In event handler I have used following events on my page with partial refresh.

```
   <xp:this.onStart><![CDATA[XSP.startAjaxLoading()]]></xp:this.onStart>
   <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[XSP.endAjaxLoading()]]></xp:this.onComplete>
   <xp:this.onError><![CDATA[XSP.endAjaxLoading()]]></xp:this.onError>
```

How can I achieve this function by using this code on both clients and on One UI 2.1.

I really appreciate your responses received on my initial question and do expect the same.

Best Regards,
Qaiser Abbas

Comment: You found relevant links with code already. Implement those in your application. If you have problems then come back here and describe your issue. We are happy to help you then.

Comment: Thanks @KnutHerrmann I really appreciate your prompt response. Actually I don't know how to implement this I have tried a lot e.g. this is very simple example. http://xpagesera.blogspot.com/2012/05/add-ajax-loading-control-in-xpages-for.html

Comment: How to implement this example. Where to enter this??? . Add following lines to the EventHandler of your button/link which is going to be used for Partial Update: 
<xp:this.onStart><![CDATA[XSP.startAjaxLoading()]]></xp:this.onStart>
<xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[XSP.endAjaxLoading()]]></xp:this.onComplete>
<xp:this.onError><![CDATA[XSP.endAjaxLoading()]]></xp:this.onError>

Comment: @KnutHerrmann following is the error when paste above code in event handler Description Resource Path Location Type
Property tag xp:this.onComplete not allowed in the property action. test.xsp HMS.nsf/XPages line 22 XPages Problem

Comment: Sample code - what you tried please. Edit your question. So we see you want to solve an issue, not just have someone write your code

Comment: I have modified the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example XPage for your second link [Add AJAX “Loading..” control in XPages for Partial Updates](http://xpagesera.blogspot.de/2012/05/add-ajax-loading-control-in-xpages-for.html):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" style="margin:200px">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:dojoModule name="extlib.dijit.Loading" />
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:button id="button1" value="Show time in 3 seconds">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial"
            refreshId="panel1">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                viewScope.clickTime = new Date();
                var waitUntil = viewScope.clickTime.getTime() + 3000; 
                while(waitUntil > new Date().getTime()) {
                    // wait 3 seconds
                }
            }]]></xp:this.action>
            <xp:this.onStart><![CDATA[XSP.startAjaxLoading()]]></xp:this.onStart>
            <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[XSP.endAjaxLoading()]]></xp:this.onComplete>
            <xp:this.onError><![CDATA[XSP.endAjaxLoading()]]></xp:this.onError>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:panel id="panel1">
        <xp:text
            escape="true"
            id="computedField1"
            value="#{viewScope.clickTime}"
            style="font-size:48pt">
            <xp:this.converter>
                <xp:convertDateTime type="both" />
            </xp:this.converter>
        </xp:text>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

When you click the button it shows "Please wait..." for three seconds and then the time of button click.

Make sure you set `refreshMode="partial"` in your button's eventHandler and a valid refreshId.

Comment: Thanks @Knut Hermann I do appreciate your kind support. This will work with IBM Notes 9.0.1 only? Let me integrate with this code with my application and get back to you. Thanks again.

Comment: I have tried this in 8.5.3 FP 6 its not working. Secondly its not working in old theme One UIapp (Application). Any clue how that can be achieved?

Comment: In XPiNC  XSP.startAjaxLoading is causing error. Moreover unable to preview on client side? Please guide

Comment: Do you have installed Extension Library on Server? It's necessary for this approach. It works on XPiNC then too.

Comment: No we are using with default installation of IBM Notes 9.0.1. Any other solution without installing Extension Library. ?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any method which I can use to display image start of the script and stop image at the end of SSJS script ?? I have tried in so many ways but failed. This will help me to show Processing . . . ..  Please wait !!!! text when search button is pressed.

Comment: You can add your own client side code into events onStart and onComplete to show and to hide an image.

Comment: This will work on XPiNC and browsers? onStart and onComplete is not available on client side.

Comment: Events are available on client side. Just replace XSP.startAjaxLoading(). with your client side code.

Comment: Thanks much appreciated. I have achieved the required functionality by  (show/hide) image on onStart and onComplete event of action. Thanks for your help throughout.

Comment: Great to hear you got it work without ExtLib. I am glad I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

With the first option (this may require bootstrap, so OpenNTF version of Extension Library), this is a self-contained custom control that automatically hijacks any partial refresh and adds a loading mask. If you follow the link to the previous version, it gives the implementation instructions:

"Add this to a custom control and add that to your xpages to get a standby dialog on every partial refresh"

The second two links are more manual options. The `onStart`, `onError` and `onComplete` are properties of an EventHandler. You cannot access them from the component containing the EventHandler (e.g. Button, Edit Box etc). You need to go to the source pane, click into the EventHandler itself, which will then bring up the All Properties box of properties for the *EventHandler*, not the *Component* containing the EventHandler.

Comment: I really appreciate your response. Can you please suggest if I select 1st option than do I need to change some thing server or client side e.g. installation. Actually I personally like your solution on thing which I require is control addition in my existing application. Remember I am having default version of extension library came with IBM Notes 9.0.1 Social edition.

Comment: onStart, onComplete, onError are not working XPiNC. Any clue?